# Ubuntu 12.04 - lockout

Tags: 12.04

Having tried to update in Nividia drivers I rebooted my pc, instead of my usual signin screen screen I got the following screen:
User name
Password
Then:
xxxx@xxxx-desktop:~$. - what command or text must I enter to get back into my Ubuntu?

Comment: Post a snapshot please.

Comment: Seems like you borked the graphics adapter driver setup. Please post the output of `sudo dmesg` and the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Answer (score 0):

More info would be nice:
   How did you update your drivers?

Anyway I have seen once or twice that a kernel update or graphics driver update didn't work out. Maybe because of a bug or something... In that case you can try to startup with an older kernel. If that works, it's now problem to go back to the old kernel (with the older, working driver) until yet a newer version is released.

Please try this. For tips on how to do this: [how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

If this works, let us know and we'll help you uninstalling the not-working kernel and making sure that it will not be used again...